# Javaplot under windows 7 and gnuplot 4.6 - disappearing result

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, gnuplot, javaplot

I want to return to the old thing: 
[JavaPlot and gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331548/javaplot-and-gnuplot/9356361#9356361)

I'm using windows 7 and I have the same problem, it means that my graph disappear immediately after the launching my simple test program:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    JavaPlot p = new JavaPlot("F:/Programs/GnuPlot/bin/pgnuplot.exe");

    p.addPlot("sin(x)");
    p.setPersist(true);
    p.plot();
}
```

Moreover this line

```
p.setPersist(true);
```

does not change anything, I can use true or false and there is the same result as above.

I'm using gnuplot 4.6 and there is no file called "GnuPlotParameters" like in earlier solution. Is there anyone who used javaplot under windows 7 and gnuplot 4.6, and had the same problem?
I created new question because the old one was closed.

Best 
Janusz

Comment: Is this problem unique to gnuplot 4.6?  Also, have you tried moving the setPersist command before the plot command?  Not sure if that would change anything.

Comment: That other question isn't closed as far as I can see ...

Comment: I've just tried 4.4.2 version but with the same result. I moved setPersist command in every possible place but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with default gnuplot distribution unde Windows.
See this [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1308/).

Also more info what to do with it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20373637/2604213).

**EDIT**: There is a new version of JavaPlot which is supposed to fix this issue.