# GNUPlot disappears immediately after its creation

Tags: java, plot, gnuplot, javaplot

I have created the `gnuplot`, but the problem is that it disappears immediately. I tried different solutions proposed in other threads, but none of them worked. Solution 1: comment the line `bf.append("quit").append(NL);` in the file `GNUPlotParameters.java`. Solution 2: put the line `gp.setPersist(true);` before `gp.plot();`.

```
DataSetPlot plotdata = new DataSetPlot(Xvals);
plotdata.setTitle("");
GNUPlot gp = new GNUPlot("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin\\pgnuplot.exe");
gp.addPlot(plotdata);
gp.plot();
gp.setPersist(true);
```

So, how to solve this problem?

P.S. I'm running this code on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems to be a bug in gnuplot under windows.
See [this bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1308/).

If you want this type of functionality, you have two options:

1. use [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) version of gnuplot
2. save the result to a file, or use the [JPlot](http://javaplot.panayotis.com/doc/index.html) swing component.

**EDIT**: There is a new version of JavaPlot which should fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `-persist` option to pass to gnuplot, you could probably change the third line in your code to

```
GNUPlot gp = new GNUPlot("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin\\pgnuplot.exe -persist");
```

or

```
GNUPlot gp = new GNUPlot("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin\\pgnuplot.exe /noend");
```

[Here is my source.](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00094000000000000000)

Comment: You can't do that. The initialization method does not allow parameters.

Comment: @Panayotis, do you mean that when calling gnuplot from java you cannot pass command line flags?  I am not a Windows user, but that seems strange to me.  I checked and there are posts (e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/L2N6cpuNLrE) where people are passing flags to gnuplot called in Windows.

Comment: You can pass command line flags, but not with JavaPlot. The single argument is only the filename executable. What you wrote will try to call the executable "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin\\pgnuplot.exe /noend" which of course does not exist.

Comment: I had a similar problem as the OP (gnuplot demos immediately disappearing) and calling them with `gnuplot -persist example.gnu` solved the issue. Thanks!