# Gnuplot script disappear after creation

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script. My system is ubuntu 14.04. When In the terminal I type `gnuplot myPlot`. The plot will disappear. It is not remain on the screen. I this stack in saw similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045540/gnuplot-disappears-immediately-after-its-creation). But its system is windows. I want to know is there any solution for that on ubuntu 14.04 32 bit

PS: when I use `gnuplot>`-- I mean when I do not use script file-- I see the diagram and it does not disappear.

PS2 : this is my simple gnuplot script file :

```
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
plot "dataFile" using 1:2:xtic(2) with boxes
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want the plotting window to remain open, you must call gnuplot with the `-persist` flag:

```
gnuplot -persist myPlot
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the `--persist` option will possibly disable mousing and any other interaction with the plotted graph when an interactive terminal such as `qt` is used. Check [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1483/) for detailed explanation.

Comment: @Wolf: `man gnuplot` shows the option as -p as first in the section OPTIONS. I'm using version 5.2, so maybe it's a newer documentation than yours was.

Comment: @userunknown maybe, now (gnuplot 5.2 patch level 6) I tried `gnuplot --help` in the command line and got this option listed (`-p --persist`), I'll remove these comments...

Answer (score 14):

There are already nice answers here, but the `-persist` flag did not work for me and enabling x11 force GnuPlot to use crapy XQuarts for windowing instead of beloved Qt. What worked for me was the

```
pause -1
```

command ([from here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1746687)) at the end of the script. According to [the documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node99.html)

> pause -1    # Wait until a carriage return is hit

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

If you do not want to call gnuplot with the extra argument (-persist), you can enable this functionality within your script, e.g.

```
set term x11 persist
```