# Gnuplot: How can I see the plot in the terminal as a result of a .gnu scipt?

Tags: gnuplot

I am currently making a script to plot rectangles. This is my script:

```
set style line 1 bgnd
set style line 2 lt rgb "cyan"

set object 1 rect from 0,0 to 1,4 fc lt 2
set object 2 rect from -1,1 to 0,5 fc rgb "gold"
set object 5 rect from 0, -3 to 2, -2 fc ls 2 fs pattern 1 bo -1
```

The problem is that I just can see the plot on the terminal for 1 second maybe. How can I have the plot longer to save it?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008941/gnuplot-script-disappear-after-creation) help?

Comment: I'm surprised you see anything at all.... don't you at least need a `plot` command?

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you want to have the plot longer to save it. If you want to save the plot and not only look at it, I'd suggest setting a terminal and output on your script before executing:

```
set terminal png
set output "myfile.png"
```

When you execute your script, nothing will show on the screen and `myfile.png` will be created on the current directory. If you type on `gnuplot`:

```
set terminal
```

It will give you a list of available terminals. However, if you only want to have a quick look at the plot and not save it, then I'd use the `-persist` option on the link mentioned in the comments. Hope it helps!