# gnuplot 4.7 and Javaplot | The windows is disappeared immediately

Tags: gnuplot, javaplot

I'm trying to see my plot using Javaplot, but the window is not even shown and disappeared immediately.
Here is my code:

```
JavaPlot p = new JavaPlot("C:/Program Files (x86)/gnuplot/bin/pgnuplot.exe");
String s=readFile();
p.addPlot(s);
p.plot();            
p.set("term", "x11 persist");
p.setPersist(true);
```

This code is running successfully when using gnuplot 4.6, but after moving to gnuplot 4.7 (becuase I need the hypertext new feature) it doesn't work.

Any suggestions? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is [a new version of JavaPlot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnujavaplot/files/latest/download) which is supposed to fix this issue with Windows.
The new version uses temporary files instead of pipes and thus it works fine with Windows, according [to this bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1308/).

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587736/javaplot-under-windows-7-and-gnuplot-4-6-disappearing-result/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045540/gnuplot-disappears-immediately-after-its-creation).